# List of available fields in twitter and google(user profile) API

Tags: api, twitter

Does anybody know where to get links to list of all available fields from twitter api and gmail api (user profile) as it is in facebook or linkedin http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

In twitter and gmail api documentation I can see just some examples of source code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Twitter REST API : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Use the console : https://dev.twitter.com/console

Check under the user/account headings. There's no specific reference for only "users".

As for google, you may want to browse through. http://code.google.com/googleapps/docs/